# How to ensure validity of foreign keys in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, data-corruption

Using Postgres 10.6

The issue:

- Some data in my tables violates the foreign key constraints (not sure how). The constraints are `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`
- On a pg_dump of the database, those foreign keys are dropped (due to being in an invalid state?)
- A `pg_restore` is done into a blank database, which no longer has the foreign keys
- The new database has all its primary keys updated to valid keys not used in a second database. Tables which had invalid data do not have their foreign keys updated, due to the now missing constraint.
- A `pg_dump` of the new database is done, then the database is deleted
- On a `pg_restore` into a second database which has the foreign key constraints, the data gets imported in an invalid state, and corrupts the new database.

What I want to do is this: Every few hours (or once a day, depending of how long the query would take), is to verify that all data in all the tables which have foreign keys are valid.

I have read about `ALTER TABLE ... VALIDATE CONSTRAINT ...` but this wouldn't fix my issue, as the data is not currently marked as `NOT VALID`. I know could do statements like:

```
DELETE FROM a WHERE a.b_id NOT IN ( SELECT b.id )
```

However, I have 144 tables with foreign keys, so this would be rather tedious. I would also maybe not want to immediately delete the data, but log the issue and inform user about a correction which will happen.

Of course, I'd like to know how the original corruption occurred, and prevent that; however at the moment I'm just trying to prevent it from spreading.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE dependencies (
    ...
    from_task int references tasks(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE NOT NULL, 
    to_task int references tasks(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE NOT NULL, 
    ...
);
```

Dependencies will end up with values for `to_task` and `from_task` which do not exist in the `tasks` table (see image)

[image]

Note:

- Have tried `EXPLAIN` `ANALYZE` nothing odd
- pg_tablespace, has just two records. pg_default and pg_global
- relforcerowsecurity, relispartition are both 'false' on both tables
- Arguments to pg_dump (from c++ call) `arguments << "--file=" + fileName << "--username=" + connection.userName() << databaseName << "--format=c"`

Comment: “Some data in my tables violates the foreign key constraints (not sure how)” somehow i very much doubt that .. provide us with create table statements and the data which violates

Comment: Unless the table was first filled, then the foreign key was **later** added with the `NOT VALID` option, right?

Comment: The foreign key existed from the beginning. I've edited the post to include the relevant part of one of the tables.

Comment: What does the following query returns for your table `SELECT relname, relrowsecurity FROM pg_class where relname='tasks'` ?

Comment: relrowsecurity is false.

Comment: Can you qualify **all the tables** from your query with the schema name? I am talking about `SELECT * from myschema.tasks`. It could have been a bug in version 10.6 but I have never heard of postgresql allowing a primary key and a foreign key to have different types. Hence I believe the most probable so far is that you are not selecting from the tables you believe.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by your comment. From the attached image in the post, you can see the query I'm using, and indeed it is selecting from the tasks and dependencies table. If I do a `SELECT * from tasks WHERE id = 1573022` (first result from screen shot), I get no results. FYI, this seems take have been happening with versions of at least 10.4, I've tried updating twice since and still get the issue.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I understand now. Everything is just in `public.` and if I add that in, its the same results.

Comment: I was thinking: the few check you have done (`SELECT ... from pg_classes`, check of the JOIN with making sure you qualify tables with schema `public`), have you done them from the database that gets dumped, before it is exported?

Answer (score 0):

This is either an index (or table) corruption problem, or the constraint has been *created* invalid to defer the validity check till later.

`pg_dump` will never silently "drop" a constraint — perhaps there was an error while *restoring* the dump that you didn't notice.

The proper fix is to clean up the data that violate the constraint and re-create it.

If it is a data corruption problem, check your hardware.

There is no need to regularly check for data corruption, PostgreSQL is not in the habit of corrupting data by itself.

The best test would be to take a `pg_dump` regularly and see if restoring the dump causes any errors.

Comment: At some point, and I do not know how, the database gets data which is invalid. In the dump/restore process (like you said, probably restore) the constraint gets 'dropped' because of the invalid data. By changing some options on the pg_restore command, we're able to detect the failure and abort the transaction, thereby at least preventing further corruption. It still does not explain how the initial DB got corrupted; nor provide a way to fix the original errors. The reason why I would want a way to check constantly, is to more or less see what the user is doing to cause the error. Error logging

Comment: Data corruption is not caused by the user, but by hardware or software bugs. Things to watch out for are crashes (particularly if the storage isn't reliable) and error messages in the log.

Comment: It happens to one user, consistently, on three separate computers. So, hardware I'm reluctant to think is an issue there. The next time she is in, where the issue occurs, I will look through her logs.

Comment: Do I understand that correctly: you have a PostgreSQL database that dumps and restores fine, then a certain user connects and does some database work, and afterwards the database is corrupt? If it happens on several machines, how is the database moved from one machine to the other? Via physical backup or with `pg_dump`? If your database was corrupted, you should dump and restore it to a different cluster after fixing the problem. Database corruption can be "invisible" and can spread, so it may be that you didn't get rid of the problem just by fixing a couple of data.

Comment: pg_dump then pg_restore is how we move it around. The user ends up deleting their entire DB, and has the tables set back up. After a week or two, it seems to be back. She **says** she's not re-importing the old projects which were corrupted.

Comment: You'll have to analyze this some more. If there is a valid foreign key constraint invalid values simply cannot be entered.